# How to handle "subscript out of bounds" error inside a function? in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
Datetime <- c("2016-03-03 05:30:13", "2015-03-02 12:45:00", "2016-03-01 02:53:20", "2016-02-28 03:22:18", 
              "2016-03-02 09:42:10", "2016-03-01 20:55:50", "2016-02-28 21:14:10", "2016-02-26 05:42:16",
              "2016-03-02 08:31:15", "2016-03-02 09:13:10", "2016-03-01 00:45:14", "2016-02-26 05:56:00", 
              "2016-02-02 13:44:00", "2016-02-02 14:41:20", "2016-02-01 15:33:10", "2016-01-25 04:24:00",
              "2016-03-02 17:24:12", "2016-03-01 17:28:16", "2016-02-28 18:22:34", "2016-02-27 02:34:31")

ID <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E")
PT <- c(27,35,38,22,35,39,7,15,37,25,38,42,45,19,17,25,32,35,39,26)

df <- data.frame(Datetime,ID,PT)
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I use these lines to set the datetimes that I want to subset

```
today <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
today$mday <- today$mday 
today$hour = "6"
today$min = "30"
today$sec = "0"
Back2weeks <- today   
Back1day <- today 
Back2weeks$mday <- Back2weeks$mday-14
Back1day$mday <- Back1day$mday-1
```

I am trying to use functions to create ggplots to output plots automatically for every ID and I do it this way

```
plots <- function(a) { 
  if (nrow(a)>0) { 
    ggplot(data = a,aes(x=Datetime,y=PT)) + geom_line(size = 0.5) + geom_point(size=3) 
  } 
}

lss<-list()
plot_lss<-list()
UniqueID <- summaryBy(ID~ID, data = df, FUN = function(x) { c(n = length(x)) } )

for (j in 1:(nrow(UniqueID))) 
{ 
  cat(j) 
  id <- as.character(UniqueID$ID[[j]]) 

  df1 <- subset(df, ID == id)
  df2 <- subset(df1, df1$Datetime>Back2weeks & df1$Datetime<today)

  lss[[j]] <- df2

  plotdata <- subset(df2, ID == id)

  plot_lss[[j]] <- plots(plotdata)
  print(plot_lss[[j]])
  Sys.sleep(0)
}
```

While this runs for the first 3 plots, the 4th plot doesn't show up since the datetime for the ID is out of my subset range. Now the function stops here and throws an error saying "**Error in plot_lss[[j]] : subscript out of bounds**", which is fine but I want the function to continue running and output the 5th plot which has a datetime within range. How would I make the function to keep running till the end and prevent exiting out of the loop in this case? Kindly please provide your thoughts in this.

Comment: Testing for `if(nrow(plotdata) < 1) next` condition could do.

Comment: Where does `summaryBy` come from?

Comment: I wanted to get the unique ID's so I can subset in function. I could have also used "Unique" to get too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
  plotdata <- subset(df2, ID == id)
  if(nrow(plotdata) == 0)
    next
```

is enough?

Comment: Thanks @Julius . I am still learning R and never knew about "next". Thanks for pointing it out. This looks simple and does the job neatly.